# command not found on shell script run

Tags: bash, shell, ubuntu

i have a script that compare heapmemory

```
#!/bin/bash

$a=$(jcmd `jps -l | grep com.adobe.coldfusion.bootstrap.Bootstrap  | cut -f1 -d ' '` GC.heap_info | awk 'NR==2 {print $5}')

$b=1000000K

if [[ $a -ge $b ]]

 then

   echo "The heapmemory used is greater."

else

   echo "The heapmemory used is small."

fi
```

my question is when I am executing this script using `./testscriptforheap.sh`, although the output is correct but why I am getting this command not found in line number 2 and 3 I am not able to figure it out.

```
> ./testscriptforheap.sh: line 2: =1603644K: command not found

> ./testscriptforheap.sh: line 3: =1000000K: command not found
```

> The heapmemory used is greater.

[image: output screenshot]

Comment: You are asking bash to use the **standard output** of `awk` as a command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assignments in bash (and also in sh) don't use the `$` in front of them:

```
a=$(jcmd `jps -l | grep com.adobe.coldfusion.bootstrap.Bootstrap  | cut -f1 -d ' '` GC.heap_info | awk 'NR==2 {print $5}')

b=1000000K
```

Answer (score 1):

Your [variable assignment](https://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/varassignment.html) is incorrect, try this:

```
  #!/bin/bash

a=$(jcmd "$(jps -l | grep com.adobe.coldfusion.bootstrap.Bootstrap  | cut -f1 -d ' ')" GC.heap_info | awk 'NR==2 {print $5}')

b=1000000K

if [[ $a -ge $b ]]

 then

   echo "The heapmemory used is greater."

else

   echo "The heapmemory used is small."

fi
```

Comment: Please do not link the ABS -- it's a notorious source of bad-practice examples; the denizens of the #bash support channel on IRC (formerly Freenode, now Libera.Chat) ended up writing the [Wooledge BashGuide](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide) so we'd stop needing to help people unlearn things they got off of the ABS.

Answer (score 1):

...also, the bash `-gt` operator is trying to compare two *integers*.

From what I can gather:

When you issue the `jcmd nnnn GC.heap_info` command, it's the *sixth* field of the second record in the output holds the *used heap memory*.
It will be of this form `nnnnnK`, so to be able to compare just the numbers, you could do with piping *that* through a `sed`:
Then you could remove `K` from `$b=1000000K`.

So, no harm in trying...

```
#!/bin/bash

a=$( \
jcmd `jps -l | grep com.adobe.coldfusion.bootstrap.Bootstrap  | cut -f1 -d ' '` GC.heap_info | awk 'NR==2 {print $6}' | sed -r 's/[^0-9]//g' \
)

b=1000000

if [[ $a -ge $b ]]

 then

   echo "The heapmemory used is greater."

else

   echo "The heapmemory used is small."

fi
```

Comment: Much of this answer includes code that will never ever work. `$a=...` is not an assignment. Neither is `$b=1000000`. See the linked duplicates at the top of the question text (and the _Answer Well-Asked Questions_ section of [How to Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)).

Comment: Thanks for the heads up @CharlesDuffy. You're right, forgot to change those bad assignments from question before pasting.

Comment: BTW, if you're using bash-only syntax anyhow, think about `if (( a >= b )); then`

Comment: @CharlesDuffy. Ok, just read that well-asked question section. Point taken.

Comment: can you elaborate more on this sed -r 's/[^0-9]//g' , this is i was also looking for to remove k from the output but I didnt understand how sed is working here  @adebayo10k

Comment: I tried to run the script commented by you @adebayo10k but I am getting wrong output even though a value is greater than b , but its only executing else condition which is "The heapmemory used is small." , I think there is some issue with sed command.

Comment: also I am not able to print value of a.

Comment: @dantealighieri, yes well spotted. Correction made. That `sed` just filters *out* all non-numeric characters from the string it is passed.